# Python synchronous launch of asynchronous processes

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, subprocess

I want to have pool of processes, which would be executed one-by-one and asynchronous to my main program. At that I want to be able to add new processes to this pool dynamically, something like this:

```python
def async_slow_operation(arg):
  pass

processes_pool = Pool()

for x in some_array:
  res = do_some_slow_stuff(x)      
  processes_pool.add(async_slow_operation, res)
```

So async_slow_operations will be executed during do_some_slow_stuff, but won't be executed in parallel within the pool.

***P.S.** Basically, I want to launch neural network via bash over batch of downloading images, but I cannot launch multiple nets simultaneously.*

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: How to do so with standard tools (using built-in modules) or any other popular libraries.

Comment: So you want one thread to run your neural network while your main thread is downloading images? Is that correct?

Comment: @JohanL Yes, correct. I want to download images in batches and launch network on batch as it is downloaded. The main issue there - batch of images sometimes can be downloaded faster that network processes previous batch and sometimes - slower

Comment: What you need is then two threads (whereof one is your main thread) - one that downloads and one running the neural network. Then you need to signal from the download thread to the other, once it is ready to run. For this, have a look at the `queue` module for this.

Comment: @JohanL this helped me, thank you